Marginal effects for tensor products
I am new to tensor products and understand what it is doing or so I think. How does one plot the marginal effect when using te or t2?  Is it possible to extract it or do I have to specify a ANOVA type decomposition model, Y ~ s(x) + s(y) + ti(x,z)?
Sample code attached below.
library(mgcv)
data <- data.frame('x'=c(1,2,3,4,5), 'y'=c(1,0,0,0,1),'z'=c(23,26,22,21,19))

gxt2 <-  gam(y~t2(x,z, k = 4),family = 'binomial', data = data)
gxte <-  gam(y~te(x,z, k = 4),family = 'binomial', data = data)

